# Make APK from Web

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have Resto app project. I need that every outlet have stand alone APK. Do you know how to buid it to APK?

I have 2 options:

- Build using URL
- Build using Ionic Source Code

Admin will build it from admin page. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you Try Windows services ?

Comment: no, i dont think about windows services.